# Best practice architecture for Android app

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android development, but have basic knowledge of Java (comming from Python). I'm working on a simple app that will list 10 WebViews side by side, but I'm having some trouble finding the proper way to build the layout and activities.

I have - for example - an arraylist with the uri's I want to build. From this I can build the same number of WebViews. How do I place them side by side (taking 100% of the screen) and allowing the user (me) to swipe between them? Should this be in a single Activity or should each swipe start a new activity?

EDIT: Sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: Take a [look](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement them as ten separate WebViews, and then put them in a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). The ViewPager will automatically handle the swiping from side to side between the WebViews.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to show a bit of the previous and next webview? If you are on page 2 the screen could be divided in 10% / 80% / 10% where the 2 x 10% could be dimmed views of page 1 and 3?

Comment: @user2258839 Not with the default ViewPager. It may be possible with a customized subclass, but I think it'd be too much trouble for such a thing.

Comment: Probably, but this is only a "self development" project, so I trying to make "strange" things to learn new things. Maybe it would be possible to build it with fragments and have them alter their layout with fragments transactions?